# R quantmod: how to get >10 years of data?

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm trying to get >10 years of data, but I haven't been able to locate how to do this using getSymbols() or chartSeries().

https://www.quantmod.com/documentation/getSymbols.html
https://www.quantmod.com/documentation/chartSeries.html

Or does Yahoo only have data since 2007-01-03?

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
chartSeries(AAPL, type="line", subset="last 15 years")

Warning message:
In last.xts(c(13.702, 13.346, 13.619, 13.65, 13.727, 15.045, 15.234,  :
  requested length is greater than original

chartSeries(AAPL, type="line", subset="last 11 years") # this works
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `from` to a value other than the default of `2007-01-01`.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL", from = "1990-01-01")
chartSeries(AAPL, type="line", subset="last 15 years")
```

[image]